# Issue with FileWriter

Tags: java, file-io, io, filewriter

I'm running my java application on a windows 2008 server (64-bit) in the hotspot vm.

A few months ago I created a tool to assist in the detection of deadlocking in my application. For the past month or so, the only thing that has been giving me any problems is the writing to text files.

The main thread always seems to get stuck on the following line for what I would assume to be almost 5 seconds at a time. After a few seconds the application continues to run normally and without problems:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(PATH + name + ".txt"));
```

Not sure what causes this, but any insight into the problem would be most appreciated. The files I'm writing are small and that is unlikely the issue (unless anyone has any objections).

If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Which part of that takes the time, the `new FileWriter` or the `new PrintWriter`?

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: So the problem is in the constructor, the following write operations are ok?

Comment: Wow, didn't see the speedy replies! The issue is with the constructor itself. I used to use a FileWriter, so it could actually have to do specifically with that. We are usually JDK 7, but the problem existed previously with what I would assume to be JDK 6_26 (or something similar)

Comment: YOu know if it's the `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter` constructor that fails?

Comment: Well like I said, the issue was originally with a BufferedWriter, switched to a FileWriter then a PrintWriter and nothing helped, so yes the problem was originally with a FileWriter.

Answer (score 1):

Is PATH on a network drive? You could see almost any delay writing to a network file system. It's generally a very bad idea to do that with applications. They should generally write all their files locally and then post transactions to a server somehow.

Answer (score 0):

When your file system gets overloaded, you can see delays with even the simplest of tasks. e.g. If I create a large file (multiple GB) and try to do a a simple disk access which is not cached it can wait seconds.

I would check your disk write cache is turned on and your disks are idle most of the time. ;)